# Why is my Azure server's IP address different from its public IP?

Tags: linux, ip, azure, linux-networking

I don't know if this is Azure specific issue or it is normal to have different IP address assigned to the interface from the public IP address for the same server.

I use a public-ip address as mentioned on the Azure portal to ssh into my machine. However, when I do `ip a` on the machine, it returns inet in 3rd block named docker0 which is completely different from public-ip. I want to access Jupyterhub running on my machine, and I tried both the addresses and none of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common thing. AWS does it the same way. Your server has a permanently assigned IP address from a private address block. You can use those addresses to communicate between your servers.

When you assign a public address to a server, it is in fact translated and the server is not aware of it. You need one to be able to connect to a server from outside.

If you are able to connect to the server, but some service is unreachable, there are a few things you should check:

- Does the service listen on the correct interface or just 127.0.0.1? Check it with `netstat -lutpn`. It should listen on the private IP address assigned to the server or all addresses (0.0.0.0).
- Does your firewall block access to the service? Check it with `iptables -L`.
- Does Azure firewall block access to the service? Check it in your Azure interface, I can't be more specific here, I don't use Azure.